# How to CREATE a FUNCTION in SQL to concatenate two strings of text?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a function that concatenates two strings of text.  I cannot simply use the concat function, I have to create a function that I can input two strings of text like String 1 = "Hi my name is' and String 2 = "Gary"

***EDITOR'S NOTE:** This is homework help. For future readers, these answers may not be applicable outside of given homework guidelines.*

Comment: Why can't you use `CONCAT(String1, ' ',String2);`?

Comment: its a hw problem, I have to create a function... I don't really understand this stuff :/

Comment: In that case (homework), you should give it a try yourself and post what you have tried if you get stuck.

Comment: Great... Now explain what results you are getting vs what results you are expecting.

Comment: so I am getting an error, "unrecognized data type. (near "STRING" at position 25)", honestly it could all be wrong I would have no way of knowing

Comment: Not sure which RDBMS you are using (that's important, since function syntax is specific to the system). But in general, you shouldn't have parameter names with spaces. Have you tried `STRING_1` and `STRING_2`? Also, you should indicate that `STRING_1` is a `varchar(50)`

Comment: yes still no luck, I am using PHP / mysql if that helps?  Does the rest look correct to you?

Comment: Does this question relate to concatenating strings in SQL or doing it in PHP? Do you have example inputs to test against? What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT NOTE:** In looking back at the original question, it asked for a function. This could be made into a function, but I think a function is **way** overkill for a fairly simple built-in operation. A user function would be a lot of overhead for something the engine can already easily handle.*

---

In my personal opinion, this is a flawed question from your instructor. The correct answer is to do the very thing you aren't allowed to do. In fact, in MySQL, it's pretty much the only way the engine *WANTS* you to do that task. However, it *can* be done.

```
<teachingMoment>
```

First, we'll set up simple data.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (s1 varchar(50), s2 varchar(50)) ;
INSERT INTO t1 (s1,s2) VALUES ('Hello','World') ;
```

To do it the way we *SHOULD* do it:

```
SELECT concat(s1, ', ', s2, '!') FROM t1 ;
```

Which gives us: `Hello, World!`. Easy, peasy.

In most* other flavors of SQL, the double-pipe operator (`||`) can be used for concatenation.

** : "Most" does not include Microsoft T-SQL. It uses `+` instead.*

```
SELECT s1 || ',' || s2 || '!' FROM t1 ;
```

Most of the time gives us `Hello, World!` again. However, using pipes (`||`) to concatenate is not turned on by default in MySQL (or MariaDB), meaning we must use `concat()`. To turn this functionality on, we can do this by:

```
SET sql_mode = 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT' ;
SELECT s1 || ',' || s2 || '!' FROM t1 ;
```

And now we're back to giving us `Hello, World!` without `concat()`.

```
</teachingMoment>
```

Again, I think this is a very contrived question that doesn't really provide much useful learning other than how to make yourself do something that MySQL was smart enough to stop you from doing. However, I guess it is useful in teaching you how to do it in other languages (except T-SQL).

Good luck.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=325e5180aecbf5b632f960e777650a76

Comment: OT: As often happens, my teaching moment becomes a learning moment for myself. I don't have a MySQL machine to test on, but it seems that I can turn on `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`, create the function, then turn it back off and use the function with the pipe behavior even after it's off. Does this maintain `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` for the function across a new session? It seems to work in dbFiddle, but that does some session sharing. I'll try to verify when I get home if I can work like I think I can. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=387e910e8b4f09d174559bd536700e41

Comment: Regardless, I still view this as a "nice to know", because I'd still have no reason, other than intellectual curiosity, to not use `concat()`.

Answer (score -1):

From comments, It seems you are using MySQL and you might use below function -

```
CREATE FUNCTION STR_ADD(STRING_1 VARCHAR2(50)
                        ,STRING_2 VARCHAR2(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR2
BEGIN
     DECLARE RES_STRING VARCHAR2(100);
     SELECT CONCAT(STRING_1, STRING_2) INTO RES_STRING;
     RETURN RES_STRING;
END;
```

Comment: ya, I actually am not using any of these, I would rather approach it myself and find out from the professor where i messed up, but I appreciate your help, seeing some examples can perhaps guide me the right direction

Comment: You are creating a function that uses `concat()` to perform the action. If OP isn't allowed to use `concat()`, this is essentially just hiding the function they aren't allowed to use.

Comment: @Shawn, This was the first thing I thought but I guess we have no other option as MySQL doesn't have any other option than CONCAT function to CONCAT strings except turn on the option of using pipe operators.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Agreed. I think it's a bad question from the teacher that's showing something MySQL was intentionally prohibited from doing. I _think_ it can be done with normal `||` concat operators in MySQL if `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` is set. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat

Comment: @Shawn, Exactly what I meant.